# Rails API, long processing time, how to notify client when complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, rails-api

I have an app that uses Rails as an API, handling the DB, etc.
The frontend uses Vue.js.

The app takes PDF files and pulls data from them creating slides for the site.

Everything works great except when there is a really large file, or it takes a long time to process.

When a large file is processed the API does it's thing but it can take a few minutes.  After 60 seconds the client times out and gets a 500 error.  There isn't actually an error, just the response takes too long and the API doesn't get the 200 response.

I'm not that familiar with the client code, I'm the developer on the API (rails).

The API is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  I tried to increase the timeout on nginx but that didn't work.  It's not really a solution though.

We have thought about having the client ping the API every 30 seconds.  That would probablt work but it seems like there is probably a better solution.

We have thought about websockets with something like ActionCable.  That would also work but that requires a REDIS server and a ton of work.

I feel like there is an obvious solution that we're missing.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Sure. Use a background job and have the front end ping the back end for job status. When the job is complete, then do whatever presentation is appropriate. You could use Active Job with an appropriate [backend](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#backends). Personally, I use RabbitMQ with Sneakers on Heroku - which works well for my needs.

Comment: I decided on delayed job using the 'delayed_job_active_record' gem.  It works without needing a REDIS server so this seems like a good solution.